# Execute commands after ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh, .profile

I'm working with lots of remote machines via ssh.
My need is to have a common .profile (or an alias for ssh or anything else) to use with all the ssh sessions, because changing it in every machine (which I should never re-login in) it is a really waste of time.

Is there the possibility?

I've read that I can set "PermitUserEnvironment" so that I can set my own "VAR=VALUE", but what about custom scripts? For example I'd like to execute something like "set -o vi"...

Comment: Why don't you install a common .profile/.login then?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite "noob" with linux...can you explain better please?

Comment: As you say in your question, you can achieve this by having a common .profile file (or .login, whatever your shell/distribution reads). If you copy that file to all hosts, you should have the same environment.

Comment: Yes, but the hosts are too much and, more important, some hosts are used only once and for few commands, so it would take more to copy the .profile file than actually use it. Moreover I'd like to have every host like the others, so if I update my ".remote_profile" it would be great not to re-upload it to every host, but only the alias/"local file to upload just before the connection"

Comment: For environment variables, you can use the SendEnv/AcceptEnv options, although that might require modification of the SSH config on the server that you want to log in to. For running custom scripts, I'm afraid your only option is to copy and run them, or run the commands manually. You could probably write a wrapper for SSH that automatically sends commands to the remote server after login -- I'm not aware of anything like that existing already.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer here is to have a copy of your .profile or .bashrc or whatever on each machine.

Just write a small shell script and scp such a file to each of the boxes in question. A three liner like

```
for i in list_of_machines
do
   scp .profile $i:
done
```

will do it for you.

You can get the list of machines out of a file using the shell $() notation like
$(cat filename)
or generate it programatically if it is really use.

Even better still, if these are virtual hosts or some other sort of cloud of machines that are being generated automatically, put the .profile into the account when the machine is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PuTTY as your SSH client you can use the "Options controlling SSH connections" in the Connection->SSH menu. Enter the command in the `Remote command' box. Save the setting as Default Settings and it will be pre-set for all new sessions.

Comment: But then you won't have a login shell, but only the output of the executed command...